# Unir columnas de diferentes tablas

Tags: sql, join

¿Como uno columnas de varias tablas asociadas al mismo ID?

Tengo 2 tablas, una de examenes y otra de tareas, ambas tienen diferentes columnas pero tienen una columna en comun la de userid:

```
Select mdl_assign_grades.userid, mdl_quiz_grades.grade AS quiz, mdl_assign_grades.grade AS tarea from mdl_assign_grades
left join mdl_quiz_grades ON mdl_assign_grades.userid = mdl_quiz_grades.userid
```

Quiero que las dos columnas de QUIZ Y TAREA queden en una misma columna.La idea es unir las dos tablas con el mismo user_id y que queden en una nueva tabla asi:

[image: resultado]

Comment: que datos querrias unir en la misma columan? para que base de datos?

Comment: Querés que los datos se unan en una misma columna o que el resultado muestre tres columnas: el user id (común), la columna de examenes y la columna de tareas.

Comment: Juan, quiero que las dos columnas queden en una sola columna, asociadas al mismo id. 
Lo mas probable es que deba crear una nueva tabla

Answer (score 0):

Las uniones en vertical se realizan con el operador de conjuntos UNION

En un escenario según las imágenes

```
CREATE TABLE mdl_assign_grades ([user_id] int, grade float)
CREATE TABLE mdl_quiz_grades ([user_id]int , grade float)
```

Como no se los tipos de datos, y veo un decimal en algunos números, yo he optado por float

```
Insert into mdl_assign_grades ([user_id], grade)
values
(1,5),
(1,4.5),
(2,5),
(2,3),
(3,1),
(4,0);

Insert into mdl_quiz_grades([user_id], grade)
values
(1,2),
(3,4.5),
(4,5),
(5,3);
```

Ahora ya tenemos el escenario.

Lo primero es utilizar el operador de conjuntos UNION

```
SELECT [user_id], grade FROM mdl_assign_grades
UNION
SELECT * FROM mdl_quiz_grades;
```

[image: Resultado]

Al disponer de las mismas columnas y del mismo tipo, no se tienen porque definir, ya que al operador union le valen, con que en el primer conjunto vea o sepa extraer su nombre y de los siguientes conjuntos, contengan por posición los mismos tipos de datos.

Aunque con esto es suficiente, si el objetivo es insertarlos en otra tabla, del ejemplo se ve que el orden no es el mismo. **Nota**: No soy capaz de averiguar cual es el orden de los datos en el ejemplo.

Order by cuando se utiliza con este operador se utiliza al final y se refiere a la union de los conjuntos. Si se quiere establecer un orden entre conjuntos, se puede hacer utilizando una tabla derivada. Por ejemplo, vamos a ordenar primero por USER_ID y luego por los valores que pertenezcan a mdl_assign_grades, despúes van los que pertenezcan a mdl_quiz_Grades y por último se ordena por grade.

```
Select d.[user_id], d.[grade] from (
Select *, 0 as colOrden from mdl_assign_grades
union
Select *, 1 as colOrden from mdl_quiz_grades
)d
order by [USER_ID] asc, colorden, grade desc
```

Para ello, hacemos el conjunto en una tabla derivada, y le incluimos una columna que nos marca cada fila a que tabla pertenece. En la salida de la tabla derivada, utilizamos order by contra la columna añadida, pero no la visualizamos, y nos determina el orden que necesitamos.

[image: Resultado]

[Operador union y union all](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/07/union-vs-union-all/)

[Tablas derivadas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/06/tabla-derivada/)

Comment: Gracias @Javi fer2, sin embargo no me hice entender bien.
Lo que quiero es que ambas notas esten en la misma columna pero no sumarlas en una sola fila como tu explicaste.
Mi ideal es que ambos valores `mdl_assign_grades.grade` y `mdl_quiz_grade.grade` esten en una sola columna, en una nueva tabla y asociadas al mismo id, para poder realizar funciones agregadas sobre esa columna.

Comment: Porque en una nueva tabla?. Si lo haces así, una vez hayas alimentado los valores, para crear la tabla. Luego que vuelves a insertar los valores. Puedes hacerlo en una vista. ¿No sería mejor? Creas una vista, con el operador + o con Concat que resuelva lo que quieres en la consulta y ya puedes utilizar funciones de agregación. Si tienes problemas con lo que te cuento dímelo y te cambio la respuesta, para que veas la vista.

Comment: Quiero almacenar en una tabla todas las notas que ha sacado un alumno en todos los cursos, para poder sacar su promedio, maxima nota, etc. NO quiero sumar todas las notas como lo estas haciendo con UNION,solamente quero convertir las columnas en filas, me entiendes?
Quiero que queden en una tabla para poder extraer la informacion de esa tabla para otros motivos.

Comment: Lo cierto es que no. Puedes editar la pregunta, con un pequeño ejemplo de lo que tienes en origen, y lo que deseas que te de la respuesta.

Comment: Listo, coloque un ejemplo con una imagen para hacerme entender mejor

Comment: Modificada la respuesta, según tu ejemplo

Comment: Entiendo lo que tratas de explicar, pero no es lo que se desea, estas juntando los valores comunes cuando lo que quiero unicamente es "traspolar" de columnas a filas, con UNION estoy eliminando filas pues se estas eliminando los valores duplicados (un estudiante puede tener muchas notas en el mismo valor)

Comment: UNION NO elimina duplicados. Eso lo hace UNION ALL. Puedes insertar todos los valores duplicados que quieras. La solución propuesta hace lo que pones en el ejemplo. "Traspolar" columnas a filas, no es lo que estás mostrando en la salida solicitada.